# How can I reduce the time complexity of this python script?

Tags: python, performance, time-complexity

Here's the problem description:

Sum of Pairs

Given a list of integers and a single sum value, return the first two values (parse from the left please) in order of appearance that add up to form the sum.

sum_pairs([11, 3, 7, 5],         10)
== [3, 7]

My solution:

```
import collections

def sum_pairs(ints, s):
    beforenums = collections.defaultdict()
    for index_before, num in enumerate(ints[1:]):
        beforenums[ints[index_before]] = index_before
        try:
            r = beforenums[s-num]
        except KeyError:
            pass
        else:
            return [s-num, num]
        
    return None
```

This solution works and I was able to get it down to O(n) time complexity. is there a way to reduce the execution time any further, I'm still timing out on codewars. the problem says I will be supplied lists upwards of 10,000,000 elements. The full problem is found here: https://www.codewars.com/kata/54d81488b981293527000c8f/train/python

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/faq/design.html#how-fast-are-exceptions

Comment: Exceptions won't help with time complexity, but yeah, it's a good idea to avoid them. More importantly, they probably want early bailout on the large test cases, but `ints[1:]` already traverses the whole thing. Skip the first element by hand -- still O(n) but the constant factor is halved, or better, depending on the test cases.

Comment: I'm curious why you are using a defaultdict?

Comment: @ggorlen The second of the four "Excruciatingly Long List Tests" has 10 million elements and the winning pair is at the very end. The fourth has 10 million elements and no winning pair. So the fast O(n) of `ints[1:]` actually plays a minor role overall, compared to the slow O(n) of the rest.

Comment: Seems like whole thing would be cleaner if you made `beforenums = set()`. Then `if s - num in beforenums:` will be true when you found the pair `[s - num, num]`, otherwise `beforenums.add(num)`. You don't need `enumerate`.

Comment: Thank you!! First got rid of the exception and that did it! Didn't think about the slicing piece either, should have thought of that as well as I had googled that earlier.

Comment: @ggorlen Now did a proper test, with the site's actual test cases but on a stable computer. The OP's code takes about 11.2 seconds. With a `return` as the first statement in the loop (so it does the `ints[1:]`), it takes about 0.35 seconds.

Comment: Oh and instead replacing the exception shenanigans with `if s-num in beforenums:` drops the time to about 3.7 seconds, so they're indeed the most time consuming thing.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use set() to make it running faster.

```
def sum_pairs(ints, s):
    cache = set()
    
    for x in ints:
        if s - x in cache:
            return [s-x, x]
        cache.add(x)
```

Or use dictionary.

Comment: Or with `add = cache.add` for a little further speed (since this question is about reducing the constant factor).

Comment: Nice.  The speed is a little improved in the platform, but not much.